# PineScript - using own string variable in alert message

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to write an alert message in TradingView's PineScript that contains a string variable I made myself

My attempt:

```
var my_variable = ""

if(longCondition)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
my_variable = "open"

if(shortCondition)
strategy.close("Long")
my_variable = "close"    

Alert Message:    
{
"side" : "long",
"action": {{my_variable}},
"exchange": "BINANCE",
"symbol": "ETHUSDT"
}    

Expected Output (for a "Buy" signal):    
{
"side" : "long",
"action": "open",
"exchange": "BINANCE",
"symbol": "ETHUSDT"
}
```

This of course didn't work. Does anyone know how to achieve this kind of custom alert message?

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamic alert messages, you should create the string yourself and use the `alert()` function.

```
long_alert_msg = '{"side" : "long", "action" : "open", "exchange" : "BINANCE", "symbol" : "ETHUSDT"}'

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    alert(long_alert_msg, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

You just need to make sure that this function is called only once and that is when you enter a trade. In other words, `longCondition` should not be `true` if you are already in a long position. Otherwise, it will trigger the alert again.